# Supermicro X9DBL-3F Xenserver 7 boot stops

Tags: xenserver, bios, supermicro

The configuration is a Supermicro X9DBL-3F motherboard with 2x Intel Xeon E5-2403 Cpu's.

In the Bios the settings under

> Advanced \ Chipset Configuration \ North Bridge \ Integrated IO Configuration \ Intel(R) VT-d

is enabled.

After the installation of XenServer 7 the server boot's, the XenServer boot menu shows and after a couple of seconds it hangs at a blank screen.

Restarting and selecting

> XenServer in Safe Mode

in the XenServer boot menu and than log info is shown and stop's with the message

> Panic on CPU 0:
>
> Couldn't enable IOMMU and iommu=required/force

The RAID controller of the motherboard is not used, but the installed Adaptec 5805 and it showed to work fine in the installation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable Virtualization Technology (VT-x) in BIOS CPU property: Advanced - CPU Configuration - Virtualization Technology. Then save BIOS settings and power off server.

If it's not help you update BIOS.

In addition.

Change `iommu` parameter in `/boot/grub/grub.conf`. For help:

```
**VT-d boot parameter: iommu**
VT-d is disabled by default, to enable it, need 'iommu' parameter to enable it.
off|no|false|disable: Disable IOMMU (default)
pv: Enable IOMMU for PV
domainsno-pv: Disable IOMMU for PV domains (default)
force|required: Don't boot unless IOMMU is enabled
workaround_bios_bug: Workaround some bios issues to still enable VT-d, don't guarantee security
pass-through: Enable VT-d DMA pass-through (no DMA translation for Dom0)
no-snoop: Disable VT-d Snoop Control
no-qinval: Disable VT-d Queued Invalidation
no-intremap: Disable VT-d Interrupt Remapping
verbose: In Xen 4.0.0 and newer, enable verbose logging while enabling IOMMU and parsing ACPI DMAR tables.
```

Usually, you just need `iommu=1` to enable VT-d.

Or edit grub parameter at boot time:

- Press "Esc" at Grub menu.
- Choose grub meenu item and then press 'e' to start editing.
- Scroll down to the "kernel..." line.
- Press 'e' again to edit this line and then insert or edit kernel parameters.
- Go to the end of the line, press Enter to accept the editing.
- Then press 'b' to boot using that kernel and those parameters.

At next boot all changes will be lost.

Comment: I did both. Two times to be on the safe side. Didn't help. I tried installing Xenserver 6.5 and it works. Detail: After I installed it and I try to boot with the Xenserver 7 CD I see the boot menu, a couple of lines and goes directly into a blank screen. Can't install it. I guess it went straight into upgrade mode which doesn't work.

Comment: Try install Xenserver 7 in text mode. I think there's a problem with video driver. Upgrade isn't good solution.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer.